# Sparse sets of numbers with the Goldbach property

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let's say that a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{N}$ has the Goldbach property if every even number $\geq4$ is the sum of two numbers of $A$.

Are there any results and examples of low density sets with these property or any results in general about bounds of the density of these sets?

Comment: Erdos showed that there are sets $S$ with density as low as $O(n^{1/2 + \epsilon})$ are actually additive bases; meaning every large positive integer lies in $2S$. For concrete sets, it should be accessible to prove that semi-primes of finite order (say, numbers with at most $k$ prime factors) have the Goldbach property, and they are not much denser than the primes themselves.

Comment: I changed "spare" in the title to "sparse". Please roll back if this is not what you intended.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/74594